# how should this SQL be written?

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to write a simple SQL statement to retrieve dates after the 1st January 2013. This is written inside a query in ms access:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblWebMeetingData 
WHERE [Event Date] > 01/01/2013;
```

This does run but it doesn't get what I want back - it actually gets all records back instead of only getting the one that actually occurs after this date. In the table it's looking at the [Event Date] and its format is mm/dd/yyyy the american format.

Note - that if I place it in quotation marks i.e. "" or '' then it throws an error and determines that there is a data type mismatch. So how should this be constructed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the date between ## and in the month-day-year format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblWebMeetingData 
WHERE [Event Date] > #01/01/2013#;
```

Comment: The month-day-year format would depend on your location. Or you could use the ISO standard of yyyy-mm-dd which will (should) work anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the # signs around the date, this way #1/09/2008#

Comment: you were just a bit too late for this :-)